# This part of my gpu got burnt today. What are the chances of service center being able to fix this?

Tags: graphics-card

After I finished cleaning dust from computer I hit the power key and smoke started coming out from gpu. Thankfully everything is working fine but gpu is dead. 
I still have 2 years warranty remaining but I know this wont be covered in it. 
It is a gtx 1060 and I can spend 50-70$ on repair if it is possible. If it is higher than that then I will just get a new 1660 ti.

Gtx 1060 https://i.stack.imgur.com/1ZyNE.jpg

Comment: I think the GPU would be more than this. I see prices over $150.  Perhaps you can get a replacement board on eBay at a reasonable cost. Ask the vendor for a return capability if the board is dead on arrival.

Comment: " I still have 2 years warranty remaining but I know this wont be covered" Why not?

Comment: @Moab I hear a lot of people saying that this type of damage is called mishandling by service center thus not covered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No computer service center will be able to repair this.  You would have to go to a business that specializes in electronics repair.  The specialty shops arent cheap, to say the least.  Their cost and time will far exceed the cost of purchasing a new card.

Answer (score 0):

Hard to say, but manual labour is mostly quite expensive.

Another risk is that not only that component is broken, but also the PCB routes might be damaged and that will be almost impossible to repair.

My options as far as I can see:

- Find out what component it is, and if it is a cheap component, let it repair by someone you know (hopefully) who can solder SMD.
- Bring it to a service center and ask if it can be replaced for 50 to 70$ (beforehand; if you have to pay analysis cost anyway, than I wouldn't even bother).
- Get a replacement board (not sure if you can get it for this price).